# How do I make post-install scripts?

Tags: scripts

How do I make post-install scripts so when I reinstall ubuntu everything is as I want it?

Things I want to achive:

- Installing PPA
- installing my programs
- themes needs to be installed
- Settings needs to be changed (power management, short commands, startup applications, etc.)
- system reboots

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Easiest way is to gather all the commands you need and put them in a text file and make the text file executable.

We start out with going command line and do this:

```
touch post_install_script
sudo 775 post_install_script
gedit post_install_script
```

And you start putting in commands you want to be executed.

> Installing packages that are in Ubuntu Software Center.

Start with enabling all repositories and refreshing the software list because the LiveCD is outdated:

```
sudo sed 's/# deb/deb/' -i /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Look up inside USC what already is there and check the package name. Examples with VLC and smplayer:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
sudo apt-get install smplayer
```

In the same way of adding software like this you can also remove packages with:

```
sudo apt-get remove {package_name}
```

(just be careful to check dependencies first)

> PPA for installing [nautilus elementary](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/phew-nautilus-elementary-revived-in-time-for-ubuntu-natty/):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
  (check the answer about adding them command line style).

> Themes

Those are either in USC or have a PPA so you can add these with either one of the 2.
For instance I like the [equinox themes](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/equinox-evolution-gtk-themes-beautfil/) and I can add them like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-equinox
```

or the [Faenza icon set](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/faenza-icon-set-update-new-icons/)s:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme
```

---

So you gather all the installation instructions that you want to add and put them in your script each on a new line. You can speed things up by removing duplicate entries: `sudo apt-get upgrade` does not need to be done with every PPA: you can do that after adding all the PPAs but(!) before you install the software from the PPA.

Theoretically you can have 1 of these script files for all Ubuntu installations but you might need to tweak them for every system.

This is my newest attempt to creating a post install script:

[image]

What does this do?

1. update sources list
2. remove all directories in my home and create them again in /discworld2/ After that I recreate my home directory directories using symlinks. This way I am able to format my home and keep my files (they are not only on another partition but even on another disc);
3. install software I want;
4. set power management the way I want it.
5. add ppa's I want

After installing I just execute my post_install file and it will run for a long time but it will take care of everything I want (well I will be adding more and more things over time so it will get longer).

<sub>I probably can improve it by making compound statements of some of these lines</sub>

Comment: Could you give us an example of what a post-install script can look like? picture or code.

Comment: Awesome! This will help a lot! :D

Comment: shouldn't PPA:s be added first? So you add your links and then download all your software in one command! more efficent! :D
I normally do a `sudo apt-get update` and a `sudo apt-get upgrade`
before the reboot.

Comment: Yeah well... I am adding stuff as I install it and add those to my script. I already have it set up with less commands by putting ppa's more in front but the actual testing of my scripts needs a reinstall and I am not doing that yet ;-)

Comment: And it's a guideline not exact sience ;)
@alvar: new image added in. No idea if these commands are valid this way ... after I did a re-install I'll get back to you ;)
(upgrade and dist-upgrade probably need to be behind the apt-get install??)

Comment: so just `sudo apt-get upgrade` for a system upgrade of the software (like new vlc, bugs or stuff like that.) `dist-upgrade` is for upgrading form a system version to another like 10.04 - 10.10.

Comment: dist-upgrade is needed for elementary.

Comment: What do you mean? I only use update/upgrade I like the terminal more...