# Bad sound on log-in to Skype

Tags: sound, skype

Every time I log in to Skype I hear a bad sound on top of the log-in sound. (I hear both bad sound and the log-in sound.)
This problem has existed since I made the full install, (Skype is in my post-install script).
Please help this is very annoying.

I've got [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/633792/) very strange error message when I typed `skype -version`

[Another](http://paste.ubuntu.com/634607/) strange message When I typed `skype`

Skype version: 2.2.0.35

Comment: Do you have Pulseaudio package installed? If so, there is  a problem between pulseaudio and Skype... try to remove it (pulseaudio) and install alsamixer full package.

Comment: post it as an answer please and explain your answer more...

Comment: @Jorge that is not true. I use Skype + Pulseaudio and there are no problems. @Alvar the error message you got is not an issue.

Comment: has is it anything to do with my bad sound?

Comment: @alvar - postinstall script? Do you mean your startup applications?  Try delaying the startup of Skype i.e. change the command to something like "sh -c "sleep 30 && skype &"

Comment: @fossfreedom no I mean post-install scrpits.
http://askubuntu.com/q/47404/10698

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is sometimes there is a very easy solution to strange problems.

`sudo apt-get remove skype && sudo apt-get install skype`

Comment: I was going to suggest this and I can't believe I didn't :P

Comment: I can't believe that it worked! :P

Comment: indeed weird...

Comment: It does not work on my machine (MacBook pro 5.3)

Comment: @XI'an I suggest you start your own question and point out that this answer didn't work. I will try and help you so it doesn't gets closed as a duplicate. good luck! :)

Comment: @Alvar Like Xi'an the easy solution did not work, so I started a new question. Please help it does not get closed as duplicate: [Skype sounds bad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157891/skype-sounds-sizzle-distorted-bad). And perhaps you have another solution.