# Is there any way to install multiple software at a single command via terminal?

Tags: command-line, software-center

I just want to know after install  ubuntu newly it`s  need to install previous essential software again,That is really time consuming so is there any way that I write command and my essential software download and install automatically.

Answer (score 4):

just type this

```
sudo apt-get install program1 program2 program3
```

in a terminal to install many programs in the same command. Or you can use install scripts. Which are basically .sh files that have these commands in them, example below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Put it in a file and name it like `script.sh` and run it from a terminal.

Also look at this answer for more info,

- [How do I make post-install scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/a/47406/10698)

Answer (score 0):

you could make a script like...

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install minicom vlc
```

and just keep adding more packages you want installed

Comment: You can just do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install minicom vlc ubuntu-core` etc. No need for so many &&s.