# How to install a list of packages using apt-get?

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a fresh install of Lubuntu and would like to install packages from a given list, without having to type `sudo apt-get install package_name`. Is it possible?

I'm not talking about the post-install scripts, that is something entirely different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make post-install scripts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47404/how-do-i-make-post-install-scripts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, just list all packages in a line separated by a space. e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install package_name1 package_name2 package_name3 package_name4
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I stop apt-get from asking me Y/n questions whether I really want to install the package?

Comment: Add the `-y` option. It's pretty long, but you can read `man apt-get` for more information.

Answer (score 38):

If you have file (say `pkglist`) which contains list of packages to be installed like:

```
pkg1
pkg2
pkg3
```

or

```
pkg1 pkg2 pkg3
```

Then you can install those packages with `apt` by any of the following commands:

1. `sudo apt-get install $(cat pkglist)`
2. `xargs sudo apt-get install < pkglist`
3. **`for i in $(cat pkglist); do sudo apt-get install $i; done`**

3rd one is recommended as it does work even if some `pkgs` are not found in the repository whereas 1st two would fail to install the available packages as addressed in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541781/how-to-install-a-list-of-packages-using-apt-get/543573?noredirect=1#comment2625403_543573)

For more information on `apt-get install` visit `man apt-get` install section.

Comment: If you want this to install along any requirements you'll have to do `xargs sudo apt-get -y install < pkglist`

Comment: +1 If you list one package per line, the file **must** use Unix line endings or apt-get will fail.

Comment: You can also pass the filename directly to xargs with the -a or --arg-file option: `xargs -a pkglist sudo apt install`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -y $(cat pkglist)` and `xargs -a pkglist sudo apt-get install -y` are not reliable. Evidence: Let the content of `pkglist` be `idnotexist
sbcl
definitelynot`. Neither of the one-liners above will install sbcl.

Comment: @JohnSmith Thanks for informing about this bug!

Comment: @Pandya, I think it would be nice to add that the line endings in the “pkglist” file should be in UNIX format. For EditorConfig users this is resolved by adding [**`end_of_line = lf`**](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#end_of_line). This is important to add because in case of non-UNIX line endings the user [**receives an uninformative error message `E: Unable to locate package`**](https://app.travis-ci.com/github/Kristinita/SashaTravis/builds/268186064#L247) and may not understand what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: I’m using the command `sudo apt install $(egrep --invert-match "^(#|$)" pkglist)`. It allows adding [**single-line comments starting with `#`**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26293/237999) (for example, `# This is my Comment`) and [**blank lines**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3432574/5951529) to the “pkglist” file. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSmith Check the updated answer.

Comment: @СашаЧерных I updated answer providing simpler solution. Check it.

Answer (score 2):

Put all the package names into a file (one package name for each line). And then run the below command to install the given packages automatically.

```
while read -r line; do sudo apt-get -y install "$line"; done < /path/to/the/packages/file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
vlc
firefox
$ while read -r line; do sudo apt-get install "$line"; done < file
[sudo] password for avinash: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vlc is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 499 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  ttf-lyx
The following packages will be upgraded:
  firefox
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 498 not upgraded.
Need to get 35.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 24.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main firefox amd64 33.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [35.8 MB]
0% [1 firefox 67.0 kB/35.8 MB 0%]                           10.4 kB/s 57min 16s^
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a lot slower than just putting the packages on one line, as it has to read package lists and build dependency trees, etc. for each package, rather than doing it once?