# Installing packages and configuring post Ubuntu install

Tags: bash, system-installation, configuration

I want to install some packages and configure Ubuntu after Ubuntu is installed on my laptop.

I have found that we can use `.sh` files to create such things. But I think it is not very robust. For example, if something happens during installation and I ran the `.sh` file again, it will start things from the beginning. Also if I want to append multiple lines to the `~/.bashrc` file, it is not very convenient.

I have found Docker as a potential solution but it is not made to set up your local environment.

Is there a robust and systematic way of doing it?

This could be also useful if I am spinning a VM on Cloud platform and want to have few things installed/configured.

Comment: I think `cloud-init` can be used. I also found `Ansible`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make post-install scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47404/how-do-i-make-post-install-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

Look up [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/), which has been the way to customize Ubuntu VMs and containers for years.

It also works on most newer Ubuntu bare-metal installers.